# How to sort by time on populate result in node using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have 2 schema. Named user and friends.

user schema is as follows:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {type: String},
    last_name: {type: String},
    update_at: {type: Date}
})
```

Friends Schema is as follows:

```
var userfollowersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {type: String, ref: '"'User'"'},
    friends_id: {type: String, ref: 'User'}
})
```

I am populating friends id using below query. [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
.populate('friends_id', '_id update_at', null, {sort: { 'update_at': -1 } })
```

I also tried:

```
.populate({
    path: 'friends_id',
    select: ('_id update_at'),
    options: {
        sort: '-following_id.update_at'
    }
})
```

But it is working with _id. I have got the result:

```
[{
    friends_id: {
        update_at: Fri May 13 2016 15:46:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
        count: 1,
        _id: 5735a23168264e700b17e6ee
    },
    _id: 5735a2bb68264e700b17e6f2
}, {
    friends_id: {
        update_at: Fri May 13 2016 15:47:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
        count: 0,
        _id: 5735a24168264e700b17e6ef
    },
    _id: 5735a2c068264e700b17e6f3
}, {
    friends_id: {
        update_at: Fri May 13 2016 18:47:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
        count: 2,
        _id: 5735a25868264e700b17e6f0
    },
    _id: 5735a2c568264e700b17e6f4
}]
```

Q : *how to sort populate result with time*?
Mongoose version -

> '"'mongoose'"': '"'^4.4.6'"',

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose, sort query by populated field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512965/mongoose-sort-query-by-populated-field)

Comment: @ThomasBormans it is different question from you mentioned question, because m sorting with **time**

Comment: The field you are sorting on has nothing to do with it. They are trying to do the same. Have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16353424/3398302)?

Comment: @ThomasBormans yes i tried this. but not working