# how to sort elements on the basis of populated object in mongodb (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i have a two schema wallet and user

user schema :-

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
 first_name: {
     type: String,
 },
 wallet_id:{
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'wallet'
 },
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', schema);
```

wallet schema :-

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
   amount: {
      type: String,
   },
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('wallet', schema);
```

i want to find all users and sort them according to their available wallet amount and i tried allot but i did not able to do so

here is me code

//------------ this is my first try ------------

```
db['user'].find({})
 .populate({
    path: 'wallet',
    options: { sort: {amount:1}}
 })
 .then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
 })
 .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
 })
```

//------------ this is my second try ------------

```
db['user'].find({})
 .populate({
    path: 'wallet',
 })
 .sort({'wallet.amount':1})
 .then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
 })
 .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
 })
```

but  both of them are not working at all i search alote but i am not getting any proper solution for that is there any other way to do this because know i am getting frusted with this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't sort on virtual fields or populated fields as those fields are only present in your app objects (Mongoose model instances) but the sort is executed within MongoDB.

Reference:

- [Sort query with populated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428471/node-mongoose-3-6-sort-query-with-populated-field/19450541)
- [The correct syntax for sorting mongoose 3.x populated document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318115/the-correct-syntax-for-sorting-mongoose-3-x-populated-document)
- [Mongoose, sort query by populated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512965/mongoose-sort-query-by-populated-field)

You can also use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) on MongoDB.

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
    { $lookup: { from: "wallet", localField: "wallet_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "wallet" }},
    { $unwind: "$wallet" },
    { $sort: {'wallet.amount': 1}}
]);
```

Comment: thx bro but can i do same think without using aggregate query

Comment: Yes, try the above solution for without aggregation

Comment: I will try to replicate your problem with `find()` and post if i got solution

Comment: You can't sort populated fields. So, the only way to sort inside mongodb is to use `aggregate`.  Answer Revised !