# Sort the data by the populated field by typegoose in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, typegoose

I have the three collections as following:

```js
export class TopClass implements Base {
  @prop()
  name: string;

  @prop({ ref: () => SecondClass})
  second: SecondClass;
}
```

```js
export class SecondClass implements Base {
  @prop()
  name: string;

  @prop({ ref: () => ThirdClass})
  third: ThirdClass;
}
```

```js
export class ThirdClass implements Base {
  @prop()
  name: string;

  @prop()
  timestamp: number;
}
```

It is simple to retrieve the data in the "TopClass" by populate so that I can access the data by "topClass.second.third.timestamp" in the TypeScript. But I cannot sort the data for "TopClass" by the field "topClass.second.third.timestamp", how can I achieve it? For example, the result sort by "topClass.second.third.timestamp" should be:

```
// console.log(`${topClass.name} ${topClass.second.name} ${topClass.second.third.timestamp}`)
TopClassB, SecondClassB, 1648142800
TopClassA, SecondClassA, 1648142930
TopClassD, SecondClassD, 1648143055
TopClassC, SecondClassC, 1648143399
```

Not Working:

```js
await this.topClassModel
  .find()
  .populate(...)
  .sort({ 'second.third.timestamp': 1 });
```

Requirement:

1. sort the topClass by the populated field ('second.third.timestamp')
2. TopClass should be populated so that I can access each field from the results (ex. topClass.second.third.timestamp)

I also try to use the aggregate but it seems to be difficult to achieve the requirement 2. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Note: you are defining the Reference types wrong, it should be `Ref<Class>` not just `Class` to have the correct types, see https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/reference-other-classes/

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You cant use mongoose `populate` in a query, use aggregation instead.

This Question [with plain mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54340760/8944059), and [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54345727/8944059) still applies to this because typegoose only handles class to schema / model translation not actual operations.

Comment: It works for me but not meet the requirement 2. How can I get the whole TopClass after sorting?

Comment: @JamesFu i dont know much about aggregation, but after the query you may need to still populate the documents on the specific paths (or if it works another `$lookup`), assuming i understand your question correctly