# Sort by a field within a populated field with pagination (without having to query all the parent document before sorting)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have these MongoDB schemas:

```
var Wizard = new Schema({
    name  : { type: String }
, spell  : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Spell' }
});

var Spell = new Schema({
    name    : { type: String }
,   damages : { type: Number }
});
```

And if I simply query the documents, here's the sample JSON.

```
[{
    name: 'Gandalf',
    spell: {
            name: 'Fireball',
            damages: 20
        }
}, {
    name: 'Saruman',
    spell: {
            name: 'Frozenball',
            damages: 10
        }
}, {
    name: 'Radagast',
    spell: {
            name: 'Lightball',
            damages: 15
        }
}]
```

I would like to query the documents from the `Wizard` schema, but sort based on `spell.damages`. This is a question that was similarly asked here: [Mongoose, sort query by populated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512965/mongoose-sort-query-by-populated-field)

The approaches I explored online are not satisfactory because they usually involve an aggregation pipeline that first queries all the documents in the `Wizard` collection, populate the `spell` field, and then finally sort based on `spell.damages` field.

What I want to achieve is to be able to paginate the query while simultaneously sort based on `spell.damages` field. Specifically, I want to avoid the step where the pipeline first queries all the documents in the `Wizard` collection because I'm assuming that costs a lot when the documents within that collection is large.

The only approach I have thought of is to copy the `spell.damages` field to the `Wizard` documents, but this leads to the need to maintain the information on both the `Wizard` collection and `Spell` collection when the value changes.

Does anyone have any advice or another approach?

Comment: use mongoDb aggregation

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to improve performance is this scenario that hasn't been covered in the link is to create an [On-Demand Materialized View](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/#comparison-with-on-demand-materialized-views) because:

> On-demand materialized views provide better read performance than standard views because they are read from disk instead of computed as part of the query. This performance benefit increases based on the complexity of the pipeline and size of the data being aggregated.

Create the view function in mongosh:

```
sortWizardsWithSpells = function() {
    db.wizards.aggregate( [
        { $lookup: { from: 'spells', localField: 'spell', foreignField:'_id', as: 'spell' }},
        { $unwind: { path: "$spell" } },
        { $sort: { "spell.damages" : 1 } },
        { $merge: { into: "wizardsWithSpells", whenMatched: "replace" } }
    ] );
};
```

Execute the function to populate the collection (view):

```js
sortWizardsWithSpells();
```

Now when you a perform a query on the `wizardsWithSpells` collection (view):

```js
db.wizardsWithSpells.find()
```

you can paginate the pre-populated view.

**Note**: You will need to execute the `sortWizardsWithSpells` function whenever you need to refresh the view. This may not be optimal if that view needs to be refreshed frequently.

Comment: Thank you for this approach! Although it does help in the sense that I do not have to run a query to re-read the documents in `Wizard` collection and able to instead read it from disk from a prepopulated view, as you mentioned, it doesn't work when the view needs to be refreshed frequently.

Unfortunately for my case, the view will be refreshed frequently (though I should have included that as part of the question, which I didn't).

Comment: You're welcome. If you are specifically using mongoose then you can use the very helpful `Model.populate` to solve this issue. See [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Having [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) will improve performance but means having to manage the data in two places whereas using refs means you have to do the lookup which will impact performance but keeps document size down and you only need to manage the data in one place. Tough choice. Good luck with your project.